# How does the extensions.py work within python package

Tags: python-3.x

I am reading other people's code and found extensions.py in their package.
I can see the modules imported in the extensions.py are imported in **init**.py as well.
I could not find how the extensions.py works with **init**.py and in what situation you need to use the extensions.py.
Could anyone give me some explaination or provide some link that explain it?

In **init**.py

```
 from flask_app.extensions import cors, guard
```

In extension.py

```
from flask_praetorian import Praetorian
   cors = CORS()
   guard = Praetorian()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Python’s package tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) this is the minimal structure:

```
packaging_tutorial/
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── setup.cfg
├── src/
│   └── example_package/
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── example.py
└── tests/
```

Seems as its just a backup for installing requirements, or for more readability. Maybe provide where you found extensions.py, and I can take a deeper look.

You could also dig deeper into docs and see exactly what [flask-praetorian](https://flask-praetorian.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) does.

Answer (score 0):

I think It's just a backup for installing things like requirements.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).